# my php array only displays one element

Tags: php, arrays, api, loops, foreach

im trying to get the element 'message' from array but only get a return of 1 element.
however if I echo the array from the 'foreach' loop it displays all the messages but if I just echo the following:

this is what it outputs:

'message here'

2014-03-25 22:38:46

'number here'

'message here'

2014-03-25 22:38:46

'number here'

'message here'

2014-03-25 22:38:46

'number here'

I get the following response:

'message here'

2014-03-25 22:38:46

'number here'

only the latest message appears, I know for fact the problem lies because I donot physically have a array, as im retrieving data from another source, but im really trying to display only the first 2 or three messages I cannot run an array like normal, how can I write up a solution to get only 2 messages

Comment: Did you check the raw response you get from api.txtlocal.com/get_messages/ If not it could be that the same message is returned there multiple times.

Comment: Can you do: print_r($arr); ?

Comment: @ Peter M I checked the raw response, I messages there are in the right seq newest to oldest, on mine it appears in the opposite

Comment: @ veilkrand yeh I can print its the same as echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add each message to a string then echo it? If so, try this:

```
foreach($arr['messages'] as $message)
    { 
        $strMessage .= $message['message']."<br /><br />" . $message['date']."<br /><br />" . $message  ['number']."<br /><br />"; 
    }


echo $strMessage;
```

In your example you did not actually do anything with the values, whereas here I have put them all into a string to be echoed out.

If you only want a set number of results you could use a `for` loop instead, like this:

```
for (var $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $strMessage .= $arr["messages"][$i]["message"] . "<br />";
}
echo $strMessage;
```

Or a foreach loop with a break (I'd prefer the `for` loop though):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($arr["messages"] as $message) {
    if ($i == 3) break;
    $strMessage .= $message["message"];
    $i++;
}
echo $strMessage;
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: In the first example he echos the message within the foreach loop, so if the message contains different data it should display different data.

Comment: matt YOU ARE A GENIUS! it worked! showing the number of messages I need :) but matt it got the last second last and third last message, how can I make it display only the first new messages, it been like this since iv been echoing, the last one appears first and the new one appears right at the bottom of the list, any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually `echo` the whole thing;

What was printed was the last line out of the loop.

```
foreach($arr['messages'] as $message)
{ 
    echo $message['message']."<br /><br />"; 
    echo $message['date']."<br /><br />"; 
    echo $message  ['number']."<br /><br />"; 
}


echo $message;
```